# Firebird 2.5 DB - How to connect multiple applications to same .FDB file?

Tags: c#, firebird

I need an advice of Firebird Expert.
I have one .FDB file.
I need two C# programs to be able to work with this database file at the same time.
Already tried:
- to create a separate user for each program (gives error "file is already being used")
- to make sure I installed Superserver version for Windows (gives same error)
- use a "using" statement in C# (helps with files, I thought it can help with .FDB, but didn't)

It's confusing, because I saw in Internet that it's possible to connect 1024 users simultaneously, or more. Probably that means they all should be within one application. But how do I connect two applications to same file?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying to connect with embedded server instead of a 'real' Firebird server? With embedded only a single process is allowed to open the database file.

Comment: Mark, afair, starting from FB 2.5, this is not true anymore. But there are chances of he being using an old embedded server version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect from different applications using SuperServer if the connections are done by the same Firebird server (you can have more than 1 Firebird server running at the same time, if they use different ports). It doesn't matter if connections are from same or different users.

Make sure you only have 1 Firebird SuperServer running (or if you have more, make sure the connections to that DB are being done through a single Firebird Server instance), and make sure that you are using correct fbclient.dll (not the old embedded version that opened the DB in exclusive mode).